# Combine sql query. Subtract from one table and add to another

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to discriminate money from the player, take a weapon and add it to the list of gifts.
I have a code like this:

```
string itemsQueryUpdate = @"update gunitems set amount = amount - 1 where id=@id";
using (MySqlCommand itemsUpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand(itemsQueryUpdate, mycon))
{
   itemsUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", gunItem.Id);
   itemsUpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
myReader.Close();
```

```
string usersQueryUpdate = @"update users set coins = coins - 1 where id=@id";
using (MySqlCommand usersUpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand(usersQueryUpdate, mycon))
{
   usersUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user.Id);
   usersUpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
myReader.Close();
```

```
string giftQuery = @"insert into gifts (user_id,gun_item_id,count,steam_link,order_date) values (@user_id,@gun_item_id,@count,@link,@order_date);";
using (MySqlCommand giftCommand = new MySqlCommand(giftQuery, mycon))
{
   giftCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", user.Id);
   giftCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gun_item_id", gunItem.Id);
   giftCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", 1);
   giftCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link", "link");
   DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;
   giftCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_date", theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"));
   giftCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
myReader.Close();
```

How can I optimize this?

Comment: Define "optimize"

Comment: Is order_date really a varchar column?

Comment: Side note: you should be disposing your connection and reader with `using` blocks

Comment: @Charlieface in the using block do you mean?

Comment: Each object should be in a `using` block like this `using(var myCon = new MySqlConnection(connString)) {...`

Answer (score 1):

You shouls use one query for the whole operation. Like

```
UPDATE user                                  -- users table
  JOIN usergun ON user.id = usergun.userid   -- user's gun table
  JOIN gunitem ON usergun.gunid = gunitem.id -- guns table
SET user.coins = user.coins - 1,             -- substract the cost
    usergun.amount = usergun.amount + 1,     -- add an item
    gunitems.amount = gunitems.amount - 1    -- remove item from the store
WHERE id = user.id = @userid         -- specify user
  AND gunitem.id = @gunid            -- specify gun
  AND user.coins >= 1                -- ensure that the user have money
  AND gunitems.amount >= 1           -- ensure that the gun is present in the store
-- AND ...      -- another conditions
```

Comment: usergun - but i don't have such a table

Comment: @LagunaSeca - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table.